# Attempting to edit question crashes app

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, android-app

On the mobile app version 0.1.58, attempting to edit a question of mine crashes the app.

Logcat basically shows this (cannot put the complete log since I don't have adb at the moment):

> Unable to start activity `ComponentInfo`{`com.stackexchange.marvin`/`com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.AskOrEditQuestionActivity`}: `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Clicking "Ask Question" is able to show the ask question activity without crashing.

I remember still being able to edit my questions not long ago, did the recent updates broke something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was my bad, it's fixed again in version 0.1.59 coming out later tonight.